# FB.ui getting js error

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk, fb.ui

I am getting a javascript error in the following code.
The error that I am getting is "Uncaught ReferenceError: FB is not defined. postToFeed (anonymous function)".
Can someone help me with this?
Thanks in advance.

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
            appId      : '<?= APP_ID ?>', // App ID
            channelUrl : '.....', // Channel File
            status     : true, // check login status
            cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
            xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
        });

        // Additional initialization code here
    };

    // Load the SDK Asynchronously
    (function(d){
        var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
        js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
        ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
    }(document));

    function postToFeed() {
        var obj = {
            method: 'feed',
            link: '<?= REDIRECT_URL ?>',
            picture: '<?= SHARE_IMAGE ?>',
            name: unescape('<?= SHARE_TITLE ?>'),
            caption: unescape('<?= SHARE_CAPTION ?>'),
            description: unescape('<?= SHARE_DESCRIPTION ?>')
        };

        function callback(response) {
            console.log(response);
            //alert("Message posted to your wall, thanks!");
            if (response && response.post_id) {
                alert('Success');
                window.location="page.php";
            }       else {
                alert('Fail.');
            }
        }
        FB.ui(obj, callback);
    }

    function sendToFriend() {
        var obj = {
            method: 'send',
            link: '<?= REDIRECT_URL ?>',
            picture: '<?= SHARE_IMAGE ?>',
            name: unescape('<?= SHARE_TITLE ?>'),
            caption: unescape('<?= SHARE_CAPTION ?>'),
            description: unescape('<?= SHARE_DESCRIPTION ?>')
        };

        function callback(response) {
            console.log(response);

            //alert("Message sent to your friend(s), thanks!");
            if (response && response.post_id) {
                alert("Success!");
                window.location="page.php";
            } else {
                alert('Fail.');
            }
        }

        FB.ui(obj, callback);
    }
```

Comment: When/where are you calling your `postToFeed` function? Maybe the SDK has not loaded and initialized already at that point. (Any other errors/messages regarding the initialization of the SDK?)

Comment: I am calling postToFeed at the same page and sendToFriend as well. My issue is that when I send a message to a friend I am getting the message "Fail" from the else statement. But the message send successfully. I am getting another error now "Blocked a frame with origin "https://www.facebook.com" from accessing a frame with origin "http://mysite.com".  The frame requesting access has a protocol of "https", the frame being accessed has a protocol of "http". Protocols must match.

Comment: Those are completely different errors then the one you described before. As for the "fail" behavior, that's to be expected, because the Send dialog does not return a post id, since it's not _making_ a post ...

Comment: Hello again, it is making a post as the message post successfully to friends. Thanks for help.

Comment: Anyone else can help on this? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

For your 2nd problem (From the comments)
Send methods **doesn't** return a post_id in the response, that's why it enters the else block even after being successfully posted. Check the response in the console, the only thing returned is the success parameter `success : true`.

For your 1st problem
You are calling `postToFeed()` too quickly i.e Facebook SDK is still loading. Try calling the same on `window.onload`

Comment: Thank you for your answer, can you explain where to put exactly the window.onload ?

Comment: try putting it just before the postToFeed() function. And if this solves your problem, please accept the answer.

Comment: Can you copy my code above and paste it with the window.onload ? Sorry about that but I do not know what do you mean exactly. Thanks

Comment: paste this just above `postToFeed` function: window.onload = function(){ postToFeed() };

Comment: Hello again, I copied the window.onload but I am getting again the same error. Thanks